# Is there any way to get rid of the "invalid resource directory name" error while editing apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-resources, apktool

I am trying to edit an apk file, however it keeps showing *invalid resource directory name: /data/user/0/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor/files/decoded/res font* error when i proceed to build the app using apk editor android app.

Comment: Are you using apktool? Did you download it and installed from official repo? https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: Maybe you could show us some more details.